# Knowing secant of a circle and tangent to the circle, find radius of the circle

Tags: geometry

I know that this problem can be solved by using a theorem $CP^2=AP \times  BP$. Can anyone show me how to solve the problem using basic knowledge? A lot of theorems can be forgotten in the future.

> **Problem:** $PBA$ is the secant of the circle $O$. $PC$ is tangent to $O$ at $C$. $PED$ passes through the center $O$. $\angle DPC=45^{\circ}$. $AB=BP= \sqrt{2}$. Find the radius of the circle $O$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The triangle $\;\Delta COP\;$ is a straight isosceles one, since $\;\angle OCP=45^\circ\;$, so $\;CO=PC\;$, and since $\;PC=\sqrt{AP\cdot PB}=\sqrt{2\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt2}=2\;$, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

$ PC^2 = (\sqrt 2)(2 \sqrt 2).$  That gives $ PC = 2. $ Since $ DPC = 45^0 , radius \, CO = CP = 2  ; $

There is no need for $ PED.$